# How to compare multiple signals at once (in Simulink)

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've a question regarding Simulink.
Is there an easy/fast way to compare multiple signals at once?

See my example below:
[image]

Let's say I want to delay a signal for x steps and to see if the signal was positive for alle the last x steps?

I think in newer versions it's possible to feed an vector into to compare blocks, but unfortunately not in R2021b.

Is there a faster way to connect x signals with an AND block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following: after your "Tapped Delay" block, perform the comparison to get a logical vector signal, then feed the vector signal into a "Sum" block which sums across the vector. Compare this to the width of the signal. Like this.[image]

Comment: This great! I didn't think of the signals width block.
Also it's super adaptable for variable delays.
(In my case the delay depends on the sampling time.)